# Kineticjs Path feathering effect

Tags: kineticjs

Is there way to style the edges of a Path using gradient styling for strokes? Basically blur the stroke of the Path to give a feathering effect along the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, apply a shadow to your drawing...

Here's an example:

```
... // your path definition

// plus shadow effects
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowBlur: 5,
shadowOffset: 1,
shadowOpacity: 0.5
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot,  I respectfully disagree.  The author wants to know "Is there a way...".  The answer is "Yes".  A very brief question and a very brief answer.  I expanded by pointing the author in a useful direction...use shadow effects.  There is not much complexity in shadow effects--3 or 4 simple settings and you've got feathering and blur.  If you want to start with my answer and enhance it with a useful example I will upvote your answer.  ;)